# How does X! Tandem calculate mass from an MS2 spectrum?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

I am very new to proteomics, and am using the X! Tandem tool to match MS2 spectra to a list of protein sequences. I understand that X! Tandem (and other similar tools) works by narrowing down the list of proteins using the mass of the precursor ion. I understand how the mass of the precursor can be calculated using isotopes in an MS1 spectrum, but Tandem only takes MS2 spectra as input. How are they calculating precursor mass?

Thanks in advance!